# Unable to get cancel.sty to work

Tags: math-mode, miktex, cancel

I'm a newbie in using Latex. I use the TexMaths Equations editor within LibreOffice.

I installed cancel package in MiKTex Package Manager. I'm not sure where it was installed or whether it was installed properly. All I can see is, when I click on the package in the Package Manager, it shows:

```
Category: Formats\LaTex\LaTex contrib

File name:          Path:
----------          ------------
cancel.sty:         texmf\tex\latex\cancel
cancel.pdf:         texmf\doc\latex\cancel
cancel-src.tar.bz2: texmf\source
```

I just did a simple test:

```
\usepackage{cancel}
\cancel{b}
```

I got the following errors:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(tmpfile.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 1
...

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd") (cancel.sty
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.53 


! LaTeX Error: Command \@ already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.80 \newcommand\@c
                   ancel[3]{%
! Undefined control sequence.
l.81 \OriginalPictureCmds
                         \@begin@tempboxa\hbox{\m@th$#2{#3}$}%
! Undefined control sequence.
...

l.182 \@i
         fundefined{OriginalPictureCmds}{\let\OriginalPictureCmds\relax}{}
)
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\cancel.sty-h@@k ->\cancel.sty-h@@k 
                                    \let \@unprocessedoptions \relax 
l.24 \cancel
            {b}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on tmpfile.log.
```

@JPi:
If I enter the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\newcommand{\tcancel}[1]{\leavevmode\cancel{\text{#1}}}


\begin{document}

\tcancel{x}
$\cancel{x}$ \tcancel{x}
\end{document}
```

It gave similar errors:

```
! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.23 {$\displaystyle \documentclass{
                                    article}
(cancel.sty
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.53 


! LaTeX Error: Command \@ already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.80 \newcommand\@c
                   ancel[3]{%
! Undefined control sequence.
l.81 \OriginalPictureCmds
                         \@begin@tempboxa\hbox{\m@th$#2{#3}$}%
! Undefined control sequence.
l.81 \OriginalPictureCmds\@begin@tempboxa\hbox{\m
                                                 @th$#2{#3}$}%
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
<recently read> ##

<more messages omitted>
```

Comment: Welcome! What does this have to do with `latex3` or `tex-core`? Probably not `pdftex` either. You certainly can't use the code posted. The first line needs to be in the preamble of a document. The second needs to be in the body of that document i.e. after `\begin{document}`. I doubt this would produce the errors you give, though, which means they are caused by code you have not shared.

Comment: Have you just forgotten to switch to maths mode before using `\cancel`? That's what it looks like. `\[\cancel{b}\]` would work, for example. Or `$\cancel{b}$`.

Comment: If you installed cancel via the package manager how come it is in the current directory not the standard tex tree? also please post the actual test file, with `\documentclass` and `\end[document}` that produce the error so we can compare logs.

Comment: @cfr: I use TexMath Equations editor in LibreOffice to enter the code above. \[..\] or $..$ is not required, I believe. and they gave the same error.

Comment: @David Carlisle: I'm not sure where it was installed. when I click on the package in the Package Manager, it shows [cancel.sty: texmf\tex\latex\cancel],[cancel.pdf: texmf\doc\latex\cancel], [cancel-src.tar.bz2: texmf\source]. that's all I can see.

Comment: so is your test file also in that directory (which is not a good place to have it) because the log file shows cancel.sty being input from the current folder

Comment: You have not shown your test file, if it is just the two lines you show it can not work with latex at all, a latex file has to start `\documentclass{....`

Comment: TexMaths is an extension to openoffice which allows you to generate formulae as pictures. You _cannot_ type you entire code there: if you want to load packages you should do it by editing the TexMaths preamble, as far as I understand from the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the `cancel` package.  Its documentation says it also works in text mode, but that appears not to be the case.  There's an easy fix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\newcommand{\tcancel}[1]{\ensuremath{\cancel{\text{#1}}}}


\begin{document}

\tcancel{x}
$\cancel{x}$
\end{document}
```

*** EDIT ***

In response to @campa's comment,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\newcommand{\tcancel}[1]{\leavevmode\cancel{#1}}


\begin{document}

\tcancel{x}
$\cancel{x}$ \tcancel{x}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I agree that this is a small bug, but this seems quite an overkill: a simple `\leavevmode` is enough.

Comment: You're correct.

Comment: @JPI: I see the same message:
l.23 {$\displaystyle \documentclass{
                                    article}
(cancel.sty
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.53 
     

! LaTeX Error: Command \@ already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.80 \newcommand\@c
                   ancel[3]{%
! Undefined control sequence.

Comment: What's a `\displaystyle` doing before the `\documentclass`?

Comment: Are you getting the same error message if you compile the complete code as I posted it or did you do something else?

Comment: @JPI: I copied your code and pasted in TexMaths Equations editor and clicked the button. It gave the same error message.

Comment: @Alex: my guess is that the TexMaths equations editor does other stuff.  Try pasting it into a regular latex editor, like texstudio, texshop, etc.